# How to sort MS Edge

Tags: windows, windows-10

I can run MS Edge from my wife's profile, but not from mine.  All I get from mine is a blue rectangle which stays for 10 seconds and then goes.  This all happened after the last MS Update.

Comment: The Windows Event Log may contain useful information. Check the Application and System logs using Event Viewer.

Comment: "This all happened after the last MS Update." - I would uninstall this update and see if the behavior still exhibits itself.

Comment: Specifically, the `Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\Apps\Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational` log has logged messages about UWP apps. If you see something along the lines of `The remote procedure call failed`, this becomes a harder problem to track down.

Comment: [try the steps from this article](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.borncity.com%2Fblog%2F2017%2F09%2F24%2Ffix-microsoft-edge-funktioniert-nicht-mehr-oder-strzt-ab%2F&edit-text=) and create the **RAC_LaunchFlags** DWORD entry and set it to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command in the PowerShell as Admin:

Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}

Comment: What's your current build? Now the latest build is Windows 10 1703(build 15063.632)